# My excel's cell value doesn't update when new value is entered

Tags: excel, vba

When a new value is key into a specific cell, the "result cell" should update  new value with its formula. However, the "result cell" is updated only when the macro is used. Please help me with this, thank you so much.

```
Sub testing()
Dim lastrow As Long
  lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    'assume i count the row
  Range("J" & lastrow).Select                 'this is the output cell
  ActiveCell.Formula = Range("H" & lastrow).Value / 4000    'assume this is the formula, i try to get value from Col'H' & my lastrow then divide by 4000
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Excel Solution:**

Another method. To use the Function as `=INDEX(H:H,COUNTA(A:A))/4000` in Column J. That will give you the exact result as your Macro and will update automatically.

---

**VBA Solution:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J:J")) Is Nothing Then

Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Range("J" & lastrow).formula = Range("H" & lastrow).Value / 4000


End If

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Hi Mikku thank you for the reply. I guess i might have to stick with the module, the reason is my script will automatically create a new worksheet and compute few things on the new created sheet. So i am wondering is that any way to solve this? Thank you

Comment: Then you can include a line `Call testing` in your bigger script. To call your Macro. So it updates the value simultaneously

Comment: @MRABALONE .. See the Excel Solution. That might help you

Comment: Hi Mikku, i have a question
Range("J" & lastrow).Formula = "=H167 / 4000" 
For example this, how do u make the H167 become range("H" & lastrow) 
i always get syntax error

Comment: You don't need the Macro for Excel Solution. Just insert the Formula in the Last Cell of J column.

Comment: @MRABALONE `Range("J" & lastrow).formula = """=" & Range("H" & lastrow) & "/ 4000"""
`

Comment: I think it is wrong, there is no syntax error but the cell is popped with the "=601.547/ 4000"

Comment: @MRABALONE ... `Range("J" & lastrow).formula = "=" & Range("H" & lastrow) & "/ 4000"`  ... Extra Quotes Removed

Comment: i found something are odd. When i use Range("J" & lastrow).Formula = "=H167 / 4000" ; the cell update automatically. When i use Range("J" & lastrow).formula = "=" & Range("H" & lastrow) & "/ 4000" it doesn't . very strange do u know why ?